# What is the real logical meaning of deny?

Tags: meaning

The definition from Google is

> 1. Refuse to admit the truth or existence of (something)
> 2. Refuse to give (something requested or desired) to (someone)

Now my interest is on the first meaning.

If I say, "Judas denied knowing Jesus" and look at the first meaning, doesn't it imply that the truth is Judas knows Jesus but refuses to admit this, hence anytime anybody denies something we can take it to mean that whatever he is denying is the truth.

Is it correct for me to conclude that deny can only be used when a person is refusing to admit something that is strictly the truth? e.g.:

- I break a mug; mother finds it broken I say it wasn't me. This is denying.
- My sister breaks another mug, mother finds out and asks me, and I say it wasn't me. This is not denying: it's true I didn't do it therefore I am not refusing to admit the truth.

Please help me understand. I'm from Africa and English is only my third language after two mother tongues.

Comment: I think you mean Peter, not Judas (Judas _betrayed_, Peter _denied_). Also, you might want to check out [ell.SE].

Comment: Indeed, Judas' betrayal wouldn't have worked if he'd denied him. Anyway, you'd be denying with both mugs; your denial has nothing to do with the actual truth of a statement, only of what your statement is.

Comment: @J.R. thanks for the correction, I have to start going to church again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Logically, *deny* means ***`SAY NOT`***;
i.e, if *x* denies *P*, then *x* says that *P* is false.
 - `DENY` (*x, P*) means `SAY` (*x*, (`NOT` *P*))

*Deny* is transitive and requires an object, at least a pronoun *it*.
The object must be a noun phrase, and the noun phrase may be any kind of [complement clause](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/complmnt.html) except an infinitive complement. Most noun objects are reduced complement clauses of one kind or another:

- *He denied ((his) having) any involvement.*
  (noun phrase object comes from reduced gerund clause with A-Equi.
  **NB**: *deny*, as a negative, licenses [Negative Polarity Items](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf) like *any*)
- *He denied (his) leaving the room.*
  (gerund clause with [A-Equi](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf); i.e, *he* is the subject of both *deny* and *leaving*)
- *He denied that they had told him about it.*
  (tensed *that*-clause)
- *He denied what she had said.*
  (tensed embedded question clause)
- **He denied (for Mary) to leave.*
  (ungrammatical for infinitive complements, with or without subjects)

There are also idioms. *To deny someone* is 'to refuse a request from a person'; it may also mean 'to refuse to recognize a person', or 'to say one does not recognize a person'. It may also mean something more proactive, like 'to exclude a person from communion, family, or friendship'.

Answer (score 3):

> **deny *verb*** (***denies, denied, denying***) <sup>[1](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=deny&title=21st)</sup>
>   1. to declare something not to be true.
>   2. to refuse to give or allow to someone.
>   3. to refuse to acknowledge a connection with someone or something.
>   **deny oneself something** to do without (things that one desires or needs).
>
> **denial *noun*** <sup>[2](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?xref=21C10552&query=denial&title=21st)</sup>
>   1. an act of denying or declaring something not to be true.
>   2. an act of refusing something to someone.
>   3. an act of refusing to acknowledge connections with somebody or something.
>   **in denial** *psychol* suffering from a condition which involves the suppression, usually at a subconscious level, of an emotion, truth, etc that is particularly painful or difficult to come to terms with • *After the death of his mother, he was in denial for months.*

In most uses, the words ***deny*** and ***denial*** have no direct connection with whether the matter being denied is true or false.

*Both* your examples involve ***denial***.

- In your first example, you are *denying* you broke the mug, because you are afraid of admitting the truth. You are telling a lie.
- In your second example, you are *denying* you broke the mug, because that is the truth: you did not break it. You are telling the truth.

But ***deny*** is the correct word in *both* cases.

However, there are cases where using the word ***deny*** or ***denial*** implicitly means that it is *not* the truth. For example, the second definition above contains the sentence:

> After the death of his mother, he was in denial for months.

That means that he refused to accept / acknowledge that his mother was dead. In that particular case, obviously he was denying the truth.

To repeat, in most cases the words ***deny*** and ***denial*** have *no implication* of whether the matter being denied is true or false.

Comment: No, there's no implication at all. It's a straightforward assertion.

Answer (score 0):

1. I break a mug.
2. My sister breaks another mug.

In situation 1. you can admit to breaking the mug yourself. You are telling the truth.

The *antonym* of [**admit**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/admit) is *deny*. If you deny being responsible for the breakage, you are telling a lie. In other words you are claiming to be innocent, when you are not.

> I denied breaking the mug

In situation 2. you can [***snitch***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/snitch) on your sister, your mother will know who the real culprit is. You are still telling the truth.

If however, your sister puts the blame on you, and your mother accuses you of the act, you have two choices. One is to keep quiet and protect your sister, the other is to protect yourself against this false [***accusation***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/accusation). Therefore you *deny* being responsible for the breakage. In other words you are claiming to be innocent (not guilty) but this time it is the truth.

> I [**denied**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/deny) my mother's accusation